# JavaScript regexp not working in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have this regexp working correctly in JavaScript (white space in the beginning):

```
 *\u002D *| *\u003A *| *\u002C *| *\u002F *| *\u2012 *| *\u2013 *| *\u2014 *| *\u2015 *| *\u2018 *| *\u2019 *| *\u0022 *| *\u0027 *
```

It replaces some unicode characters (dashes, colons, apostrophes etc.) also with white spaces around with just one white space, for example "word: word - word" will be "word word word". So **I'm trying to remove some specific unicode chars from string.**

Now I need to use this regexp in PHP. I know that single unicode char should look like this in PHP regexp: \x{xxxx} so my new regexp looks like this and it's not working at all...

```
/ *\x{002D} *| *\x{003A} *| *\x{002C} *| *\x{002F} *| *\x{2012} *| *\x{2013} *| *\x{2014} *| *\x{2015} *| *\x{2018} *| *\x{2019} *| *\x{0022} *| *\x{0027} */
```

Comment: In your PHP source, have you escaped the backslashes? Can we see the actual PHP source you're using, and some sample text you're matching against? When you say "it's not working at all", I assume that means it finds no matches where it should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the `/u` modifier for the regular expression it should work fine.

**[Example](http://ideone.com/BHQBE7)** with the [Greek capital letter phi](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a6/index.htm):

```
echo preg_match('/\x{03a6}/u', 'Φ');
```